# Any research backing alpha waves and impact on subconscious mind

Tags: brain-waves

I've been researching the subject of affirmations and the relation with alpha waves over the course of the last few days.

I've found a significant amount of general information on the importance of performing learning/creative tasks during the alpha state, many of these sources indicating such a state as being ideal for self-suggestion.

On one of the articles I stumbled upon, the following statement was made:

> The subconscious mind is most open to helpful and beneficial suggestions while we are in the “alpha” brainwave state—our most relaxed state of mind. The alpha wave frequency is often achieved in a meditative state or just before falling sleep, creating an optimal time to receive positive affirmations.

Source: https://www.psychologytoday.com/ca/blog/embodied-wellness/201704/affirm-or-not-affirm

Such statements seem to run abound when running online searches, however, I have been unable to find any study to support statements like these; that could indicate the "openness" of the subconscious to "beneficial"/"helpful" effects to suggestive events when the brain is operating in the alpha band.

I am looking to find published research that could support to some extent statements like those.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, I believe to have found one such published article: `Hypnotic Susceptibility increased by EEG Alpha Training` by DAVID R. ENGSTROM, PERRY LONDON & JOSEPH T. HART.

In the article, they describe the correlation between hypnotic susceptibility and alpha waves. Here is one of the relevant lines:

> Results were analysed by correlation techniques and by analysis of variance and covariance. They indicate that hypnotic susceptibility and operant alpha rhythm are positively related both before and after the subjects received alpha training.